# Ubuntu 12.10 unattended installations CD

Tags: installation, 12.10, live-cd

My work require me to build an unattended installation CD for Ubuntu 12.10. I have searched on the Google but there is no clue or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You might find what you need at the following link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

It is a quite comprehensive tutorial for customizing a livecd/liveusb ubuntu system.